# Android Maps V2 Application Crashes on Android Phone

Tags: java, android, maps

I have made an app that uses Google Android Maps API V2 and I have followed every step in the guide provided by Google but it doesn't work unfortunely and it crashes every time I try to start it up, I have looked up similar problems here on stack overflow but I haven't find one that helps me unfortunately( and yes I am using an Android Phone and not a Emulator).

The issue seem so be with it not finding MapView from the Google Play Services library even though i have added that library to my application, som I'm wondering if anyone of guys have had the same problem and how did you solve?

```
03-04 00:26:51.274: E/dalvikvm(14369): Could not find class 'com.google.android.maps.MapView', referenced from method com.cornboyzmaps.googlemapsA.MainActivity.onCreate
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.name;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.name"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:debuggable="true" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.name.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="**api_key**" />
    </application>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: `com.google.android.maps.MapView` is what the error is referring to, and that Maps V1, not Maps V2.

Comment: Could you further elaborate on that please( and do you mean that it's a code for maps V1 and not V2)?

Comment: I mean that `com.google.android.maps.MapView` is a class from Maps V1, not Maps V2. While there is a `MapView` in Maps V2, it is `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView`.

Comment: Aha, thank you so much I will definitely try that and meanwhile can you give this post some attention if I where to post something(I hate to post multiple posts about basically almost the same problem).